# EntityFramework and DbContext, transforming an entity to a DTO and back

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dto

Some Background Information first:

I have a server that provides wcf soap services and a website that consumes those services. The server uses the entity framework to write/read to/from the database. During the process the entity object are transformed into DTOs and back when they return to the server.

I have the following entity model: [image]

The DTOs are autogenerated.

Now to the problem:

The `Participent` is the 'start' object that is created with a `VisibleStatus`, a `Status`, a `StatusMessage` and two `ContactGroups`. After those are created I want to add `Contact` with the already created `Participent` and `ContactGroup`.

The problem here is, that the entity framework does not realize that the participent and the contact group already exist in the database and it creates a new database entry for those. Even if they already have an id. I think the problem lies in the fact that the entities are transformed to DTOs and back.

Asume the following client side code to generate the participent, visible status, status, status message and contact groups:

```cs
MT_Stammdaten_MeineKontakte_ParticipentDTO user = new MT_Stammdaten_MeineKontakte_ParticipentDTO();
user.MT_Participant_Id = endUserId;
user.StatusMessage = new StatusMessageDTO()
{
    Text = "not defined",
    Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
};
user.VisibleStatus = new VisibleStatusDTO()
{
    Photo = null,
    Status = new StatusDTO()
    {
        Value = "not defined"
    },
    Timestamp = DateTime.Now
};

user = cClient.AddParticipantMapping(user);

ContactGroupDTO defaultGroup = new ContactGroupDTO()
{
    Name = CONTACTS_GROUP_STANDARD,
    Description = CONTACTS_GROUP_STANDARD_DESC,
    Participent = user,
};
ContactGroupDTO familyGroup = new ContactGroupDTO()
{
    Name = CONTACTS_GROUP_FAMILY,
    Description = CONTACTS_GROUP_FAMILY_DESC,
    Participent = user,
};

defaultGroup = cClient.AddContactGroup(defaultGroup);
familyGroup = cClient.AddContactGroup(familyGroup);
```

And now the code for creating the contact:

```
MT_Stammdaten_MeineKontakte_ParticipentDTO participent = cClient.getUser(endUserId);
ContactGroupDTO group = cClient.GetContactGroup(1);
MT_Stammdaten_MeineKontakte_EndUser endUser = new MT_Stammdaten_MeineKontakte_EndUser()
{
    MT_EndUser_Id = newContactId,
};
ContactDTO contact = new ContactDTO()
{
    ContactGroup = group,
    ContactGroupId = group.Id,
    MT_Stammdaten_MeineKontakte_EndUser = endUser,
    MT_Stammdaten_MeineKontakte_Participent = participent,
}

contact = cClient.AddContact(contact);
```

How can one tell the entity framework that the objects with an id already exist? Because of the fact, that most of the objects are nested, I'd prefer a rather generic solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `State` on the existing objects to `EntityState.Unchanged`.
eg, for a group

```
 context.ObjectStateManager
     .ChangeObjectState
     (group, System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged);
```

Comment: I'll give it a try tomorrow. Thanks.